# Exception in UITableViewCell using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview, autolayout

I am having this weired exception. Dont know why its happening ? Does anybody know, whats happening here?

2013-10-08 17:13:42.565 OnTheGo_Development[25599:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[ContentDetailHeaderCell_iPhone layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIView.m:5776
2013-10-08 17:13:42.566 OnTheGo_Development[25599:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. ContentDetailHeaderCell_iPhone's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x33f5012 0x298de7e 0x33f4e78 0x2423f35 0x19259ef 0x29a16b0 0xc83fc0 0xc7833c 0xc78150 0xbf60bc 0xbf7227 0xbf78e2 0x33bdafe 0x33bda3d 0x339b7c2 0x339af44 0x339ae1b 0x37e07e3 0x37e0668 0x18d565c 0x2ccd 0x2d90725)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are overwriting layoutSubviews and you are not calling [super layoutSubviews] there.

Fix that in ContentDetailHeaderCell_iPhone class as error says.

Next time please always paste a code which is causing a problem to make it easier...